# fr:autocomplete in resource mode not showing suggest list

Tags: autocomplete, orbeon

Im using orbeon form builder autocomplete control that i changed in edit mode to match the synatx of the autocomplete resource mode, like this:

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
        xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:title>Test Autocomplete</xhtml:title>
          <xhtml:style>
    .fr-autocomplete-container .yui-ac-content {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 100px;
*height:expression(this.scrollHeight>100?"100px":"auto");}
    </xhtml:style>
    <xforms:model id="fr-form-model">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <address>
                    <street/>

                    <number/>
                    <zip/>
                    <city/>
                </address>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xforms:bind id="fr-form-binds" nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xforms:bind id="address-bind" nodeset="address">
                <xforms:bind id="number-bind" nodeset="number" name="number"/>
                <xforms:bind id="zip-bind" nodeset="zip" type="xforms:string" readonly="true()" name="zip"/>
                <xforms:bind id="city-bind" nodeset="city" type="xforms:string" readonly="true()"
                             name="city"/>
                <xforms:bind id="street-bind" nodeset="street" type="xforms:string" name="street"/>

            </xforms:bind>
        </xforms:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxforms:readonly="true">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>MyApp</application-name>
                <form-name>test_autocomplete</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Test Autocomplete</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <author/>
                <logo mediatype="" filename="" size=""/>
            </metadata>
        </xforms:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xforms:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxforms:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <street>
                        <label>Rue</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </street>

                    <address>
                        <label>Coordonees</label>
                        <help/>
                    </address>
                    <number>
                        <label>Num</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </number>
                    <zip>
                        <label>Code postal</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </zip>
                    <city>
                        <label>Localite</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </city>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xforms:instance>


    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <fr:view>
        <xforms:label ref="instance('fr-form-metadata')/title"/>
        <fr:body>
            <fr:section id="address-section" bind="address-bind">
                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/address/label"/>
                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/address/help"/>
                <fr:grid columns="2">
                  <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <widget:xforms-instance-inspector xmlns:widget="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/widget" id="orbeon-xforms-inspector"/>
                        </xhtml:td>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>

                            <fr:autocomplete xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                             xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                                             xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                             xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                             xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                             bind="street-bind"
                                             appearance="minimal"
                                             id="street-control"
                                             ref="."
                                             resource="https://myHTTPServiceUrl/streets/getByCriteria.do?language=FR&amp;streetName={event('fr-search-value')}"
                                             dynamic-itemset="true" >
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/street/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/street/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/street/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <xforms:itemset nodeset="/results/result">
                                    <xforms:label ref="/Street/name"/>
                                    <xforms:value ref="/Street/name"/>
                                </xforms:itemset>

                            </fr:autocomplete>




                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                          xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                          xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                          bind="number-bind"
                                          id="number-control">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/number/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/number/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/number/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                          xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                          xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                          bind="zip-bind"
                                          id="zip-control">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/zip/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/zip/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/zip/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                          xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                          xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                          bind="city-bind"
                                          id="city-control">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/city/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/city/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/city/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xhtml:body>
```

When i test it in form runner i see that the 'fr-search-changed' event is fired and the search value changing but i see no itemset filled.
Can you tell me what is wrong in the code pls ?
Also i'm sure that the service is really returning results with what i tested

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly run your code as it doesn't point to an accessible service, but I suspect that the autocomplete [resource mode](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/autocomplete#TOC-Resource) isn't working for you because that feature just didn't make it for the 3.9 release. To be able to use the resource mode, you'll need to use a newer version (yet to be release, at the point of this writing) or a nightly build.

Comment: ok i'll let you know if it works as soon as we deploy the new release